# How to use COUNTIFS or ANOTHER METHOD to count duplicates of a given range on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of addresses, jobs and invoice numbers on one sheet and on another sheet i have the invoice number followed by a countif which counts how many times the invoice number appears on the job sheet, this tells me how many jobs, great!
Now I need to know if those jobs with the same invoice number all have the same address or different addresses.
I know it needs to be a combination of countif/s with index/match or something along those lines, just cant get my head around this one.

Comment: Needs sample data and expected results.

Comment: Can you include screen shots of your spreadsheet? How can we help you if we have no idea what your cell ranges are and what you want the output to be?

Comment: Im still quite new to the forum and havent yet worked out how to upload attachments lol! I'll try my best here....<br/><br/>
Sheet 1 = Jobs! Addresses in E:E, Invoice Numbers in O:O, <br/><br/>
Sheet 2 = Invoices! Invoice numbers in A:A, in D:D I have a COUNTIF formula for example (=COUNTIF(Jobs!O:O,A4) this tells me how many times the invoice number appears in Jobs!.<br/><br/>
Now I need a formula to count how many duplicates or unique addresses appear in Jobs! E:E with the matching Invoice number from Invoices! A?<br/><br/>

Comment: I want it to return the address given if the addresses matching the invoice are all the same, so maybe an index/match but would like the result to read  "Multiple" if there is more than one uniques address.<br/><br/>I hope this helps you to help me :)

Comment: I would like for the formula to sit in C:C of Invoices! and oooh look I'm learning!  heres screen shots of the 2 pages in question http://imageshack.com/a/img923/4595/6j0fUG.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/2907/awnVsv.png

Comment: How similar do addresses have to be to be considered the same? Will they always be spelt the same with the exact same syntax/punctuation?

Comment: A pivot on invoice number and address would give you some idea. Put invoince in row field left hand side, followed by address. Could also add address to data area to give count.

Comment: The addresses will always be identical as they are derived from an index match to a property address sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution for now I have on the Jobs! sheet created two extra columns at the end P:P and Q:Q. In P3 I have the following formula: =(O3&E3) and in Q3 I have =COUNTIF(P:P,P3).

This gives a 1 for unique and 2 for duplicates I can now use a IF formula in the Invoices! sheet in C:C to either show the address or state "multiple".

This works fine as far as i can see, but I would like to see if anyone can come up with something better, Im sure there must be a way to do all of this in one combined formula that lives in Invoices! C:C with no need for extra hidden info in Jobs!.